# How to prevent warnings shadowing errors in GCC

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, makefile, warnings, pragma

I've taken over a large and very old project recently.  It compiles without problems, but since the code is so old and the former developers weren't always doing things the way they were supposed to, I get a lot of warnings with a modern compiler.

Now I change parts of the code and sometimes introduce an error.  When I recompile the project, a lot of warning output is happening, and at the end of the output, I see a message like this:

```
SomeFile.C:3426:51: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
         SomeCode("Some String");
                               ^
SomeFile.C:3429:55: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
         SomeCode("Some Other String");
                                     ^
make[2]: *** [SomeFile.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/some/path/of/a/source/directory/somesubdirectory'
make[1]: *** [somesubdirectory] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/some/path/of/a/source/directory'
make: *** [directory] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 2s)
```

And a lot of warnings above that (I just showed two of a list of dozens).

The real error is displayed hundreds of lines above that and reads:

```
SomeFile.C: In function 'void someFunction()':
SomeFile.C:891:5: error: 'someIdentifier' was not declared in this scope
     someIdentifier->someMoreStuff->someMethod(someArgs);
     ^
```

My problem now is to find the error message.  It would be easy if I could **turn off the warnings** because then the error message would be the last thing printed.

**So is there a way to tell the compiler not to give out any warnings or at least print the error messages at the very end** (that would be enough to solve my problem)?

I want to solve this issue with as little patch work as possible, so it is more or less out of the question to fix all code occurrences issuing the warnings, especially since I am about to throw away large parts of it in the end and just keep one feature I want to extract.

I can, however, change all files (maybe inserting a `#pragma` or `#define` or similar at the beginning using `find` and `sed`), I also can patch the `Makefile`s in all directories.  It would be nice, however, to be able to switch the solution off and on without having to patch too much (if possible, I don't want to demand too much).

I found and tried some information on suppressing warnings, e.g., [this here](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/SuppressingGCCWarnings.html), but using options `-i` (or `-isystem`) or `#pragma GCC system_header` seems not to work in my case, probably because the file being warned about is the one given on the command line, not an included file.  The `#pragma` is being warned about itself because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set [`gcc -w`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-w) to inhibit all warning messages.

Comment: Seems to work!  Too simple.  I will wait and see whether another solution pops up.  Especially one what only pushes the error messages below the warnings without suppressing the warnings.  Otherwise this seems to be my solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can control the GCC warnings from the commandline. The [warning options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) are pretty well documented. Most options begin with "-W" and there is a "no" equivalent for every option. You can use [`-Wno-shadow`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wno-shadow) to disable warnings related to these sorts of shadowing issues.

You may also want to give [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) a try; [better diagnostics](http://clang.llvm.org/diagnostics.html) is one of its major strong points.

Comment: Yeah, but I've got a whole bunch of different messages, and turning each off by giving the appropriate `-Wno-whatever` is not what I had in mind.

Comment: Switching to another compiler is not an option (due to company restrictions) but thanks for the interesting link anyway!

Comment: Some of those "warnings" are decently serious.. I don't think suppressing them wholesale is a great idea.

Comment: That comment had to come, of course.  Mentioning suppressing warnings is kind of a taboo and always triggers this.  And there is justification in it, I won't deny that.  But as I said, my case is not about developing a project, it is about stripping existing old code down in order to extract a specific feature, and of course I don't want to fix warnings in code which will get removed soon anyway.  But again, yes, suppressing warnings is a bad idea in general.  That's why I would prefer a solution which just places the error messages below all the warnings.